# Duplicate users(entries) should not be add in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm facing an issue. i have a dropdown contains list of users fetching from database. When i select a user from dropdown it appends on below table and when i select the same user again it again appends on below table as a new row. So i want to stop duplicating same user in table.

Here's my View Code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 " style="display:none" id="user-container">
            <label>User</label>
            <select id="users" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
              <option value="">Select User</option>
            </select>
            <p class="validate-error"><span id="users_error"></span></p>
          </div>
```

Here's my JavaScript Code

```
PostMyData(obj, '/Admin/Meetings/GetUserGroupUsers', (res) => {
   
  if (res.Code === 0 || res.Code === -1) {
    alert(res.Message);
  }
  if (res.Code === 1) {
 
    $('#users').html('');
 
    $('#users').append('<option value="">Select User</option>');
 
    res.Data.map(item => {
      $('#users').append(`<option value="${item.UserId}">${item.FirstName} ${item.LastName}</option>`);
    });
 
    $('#users').prop('disabled', false);
  }
```

Comment: Where is the table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by **duplicating same user in table**, If you mean you want prevent duplicating user in the dropDown list you can try on this code, if not, please provide more details about the table you are working on.

```
 ...
 const usersList=  $('#users');
 res.Data.forEach(item => {
  if(usersList.find(`option[value=${item.UserId}]`).length > 0){
    return ; // do nothing
  }
  usersList.append(`<option value="${item.UserId}">${item.FirstName} ${item.LastName}</option>`);
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamically giving an id will do this job.Lets say you are giving giving id based of id value, then you can easily find if same id exits or not.

```js
PostMyData(obj, '/Admin/Meetings/GetUserGroupUsers', (res) => {
   users = document.getElementById("users");
    if (res.Code === 0 || res.Code === -1) {
      alert(res.Message);
    }
    if (res.Code === 1) {
   
      users.html('');
   
      users.append('<option value="">Select User</option>');
   
      res.Data.map(item => {
        if(!users.querySelector(item.UserId))
        users.append(`<option value="${item.UserId}" id="${item.UserId}">${item.FirstName} ${item.LastName}</option>`);
      });
   
      users.prop('disabled', false);
    }
```